# How to show a Custom Total instead of Cluster Count inside iconCreateFunction

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapquest

I want to show total number of members inside Cluster Group.

Currently it shows Total number of Clusters inside a group.

For example, this example shows `15` inside a circle. Whereas i want to show the total `sum` of `3rd parameter` of this `array addressPoints` which is a total of `14096` inside the circle.

How can we do that?

```
var addressPoints = [
[-37.8839, 175.3745188667, "571"],
[-37.8869090667, 175.3657417333, "486"],
[-37.8894207167, 175.4015351167, "807"],
[-37.8927369333, 175.4087452333, "899"],
[-37.90585105, 175.4453463833, "1273"],
[-37.9064188833, 175.4441556833, "1258"],
[-37.90584715, 175.4463564333, "1279"],
[-37.9033391333, 175.4244005667, "1078"],
[-37.9061991333, 175.4492620333, "1309"],
[-37.9058955167, 175.4445613167, "1261"],
[-37.88888045, 175.39146475, "734"],
[-37.8950811333, 175.41079175, "928"],
[-37.88909235, 175.3922956333, "740"],
[-37.8889259667, 175.3938591667, "759"],
[-37.8876576333, 175.3859563833, "687"],
];
var tiles = L.tileLayer('//{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="//openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Points &copy 2012 LINZ'
});

var map = L.map('map', {
  center: L.latLng(-36.848461, 174.763336),
  zoom: 5,
  layers: [tiles]
});

var mcg = L.markerClusterGroup({
  chunkedLoading: true,
  //singleMarkerMode: true,
  spiderfyOnMaxZoom: false
});

for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
  var a = addressPoints[i];
  var title = a[2];
  var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), { title: title });
  marker.bindPopup(title);
  mcg.addLayer(marker);
}

map.addLayer(mcg);
```

Here's [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Highviews/gw0mu1xa/1/)

Comment: This question on gis.se is a near duplicate https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292674/adding-custom-icons-to-l-markerclustergroup